# a question about md5sum

Tags: md5sum

Can i be sure, that a burned Ubuntu DVD with  right md5 checksum result is free of any malware or could there still be malware on the DVD f.e. in case it was created on a already infected PC?

Regards

boomx4

Comment: I think this is a question for: http://security.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

It depends.

If you downloaded the ISO file from the official Ubuntu download link, and the MD5 matches the one on the site, it's free from malware.

If you downloaded the ISO file from some other sites and it doesn't fit with the official MD5, there is something wrong. Recheck if you checked with the correct MD5 or redone load from official mirror links.

If you downloaded the ISO file from some unofficial sites and the Md5 matches the MD5 provided by the unofficial site BUT doesn't matches the official MD;, it might be modified or infected, or corrupted.

Hope that I helped.

Comment: No, an already infected PC could easily forge the MD5 hash of an infected image to be equal to that given on the official site. However, downloading an image from the official site is in itself a pretty good guarantee that the image contains no malware.

Comment: «No, an already infected PC could easily forge the MD5 hash of an infected image to be equal to that given on the official site.»

This can be done but for sure not "easily", also considering the space constraint.

Answer (score 0):

The MD5 check verifies that the content of the file you downloaded is exactly the same as it is on the Ubuntu Server.

If the MD5 checksum doesn't match the checksum indicated by the download site your downloaded copy got corrupted.

If you download it on an infected system the virus can infect it after the successful download and corrupt it. But being realistical a windows virus certainly will not work in a linux environment.

Anyway a successful md5 check shows you always that the file is correct and not corrupted.